# I want to check the property value whether its empty or not in MVC. Please suggest

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

Here is my CShtml code
I would like to check the Employee name for some condition.
Would be great if you can suggest.

```
@model IEnumerable<ATS.Models.clsManagerApproval>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManagerApproval";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layoutuser.cshtml";
}

<h2>Manager Approval</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
   if ($("#EmployeeName").val() == "") {
            alert("some sample text abc213");
        }
})
</script>
<table style="border: 1px solid white">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:1px; visibility:collapse;">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UAmasterID)
        </th>
          <th style="width:130px">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
        </th>
     </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td style="visibility:collapse;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UAmasterID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
        </td>
    </tr>
 }
</table>
```

I would like to check the Employee name for some condition.
Would be great if you can suggest.
Thanks

Comment: What condition? And what do you want to do once you have checked it? And what are you trying to do with your script (you don't have any elements with `id="EmployeeName"`)

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.EmployeeName))
    {}
}
```

Comment: alert(Model.EmployeeName).toString(); if i make an attempt to see the value. it's showing the exception as "Model" is undefined

Comment: @user3794063 I don't even know to start from...apart from advicing you to read a tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.EmployeeName))//here your condition
        {
            //whatever u want to do...
        }
        else{
            <tr>
                <td style="visibility:collapse;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UAmasterID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how MVC / razor works.

1. Everything after an @ symbol is razor and will be executed on the server before it is sent to the client. This allows you to manipulate the Model object using C# functions.
2. Javascript code is entirely separate from razor because javascript is executed on the client.
3. Razor will automatically detect when you want html so you can write code like this:

   @foreach(var item in Model)
   {

       @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (Model.EmpleeName) )
       {
           
               Warning: Name is blank
           
       } else {
            ... 
            ... 
            ... 
       }

   }

It sounds like you may need to do some background reading about MVC.

Comment: Since the model is `IEnumerable<T>`, this will throw an exception (who need to do some background reading?)

Comment: The question was asking how to check a value not write the whole page